# valueerror when sorting graph nodes in networkx

Tags: python, sorting, networkx

I want to sort graph nodes by their different attributes. I have a gdf file that has the nodes and edges of the graph and used networkx to analyze it. But I got an error on sorted fuction. Here is my code ("positive" is one of the node's attribute that is integer):

```
G = read_gdf("path/to/gdf file")
sorted_by_attr = sorted(G.nodes, key=lambda n: G.nodes[n]['positive'], reverse=True)
```

here is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-83d54031ff3f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sorted_by_attr = sorted(G.nodes, key=lambda n: G.nodes[n]['positive'], reverse=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any one knows how can I solve this?

Note: This graph has duplicated nodes. May this error be due to this?

Comment: What type is the attribute `positive`?  Can two of these attributes be compared?  It seems like that's where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Its type is integer

Comment: The ValueError looks like a numpy error and looks like it is basically telling you that `G.nodes[n]['positive']` is **not** an integer, but a Series.

Comment: I tried that but I got another error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the key for `sorted` is wrong.

Imagine I have this list:

```
seq = [{'positive': 12}, {'positive': 3}, {'positive': 5}]
```

To sort it, I will write:

```
result = sorted(seq, key=lambda x: x['positive'])  # good

print(result)
# [{'positive': 3}, {'positive': 5}, {'positive': 12}]
```

I will ***not*** write:

```
result = sorted(seq, key=lambda n: seq[n]['positive'])  # bad
# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```